# Remove prefix with make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to remove a prefix from a string (a pathname in my case) in `make`?

As an example, suppose I had the string:

```
FILES = a/b/c.d a/b/e.f
```

I want to remove the `a/`, and be left with `b/c.d b/e.f`

I have tried using various combinations of `dir`, `notdir` and `basename` from the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), but none seem to provide a nice solution.

```
$(dir $(FILE))      # a/b a/b
$(notdir $(FILE))   # c.d e.f
$(basename $(FILE)) # a/b/c a/b/e
```

The only way I've found to do this so far is:

```
$( join $(basename $(dir $(FILE))), $(notdir $(FILE)) )
```

Which is really ugly and long-winded. What I really need is some kind of `$(removeprefix ...)` function. Assuming that I know the prefix (`a/`) to be removed, can this be done with some kind of string manipulation?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can strip off a leading `a/` with

```
$(FILE:a/%=%)
```

See the [text substitution function reference](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) for more options & details.

Answer (score 25):

Since you say GNU make, why not just:

```
$(FILE:a/%=%)
```

?

Comment: Guessing that was since there's an identical answer above...  but which was apparently posted in the exact same minute!  Unlucky :/