# Makefile: reuse value of % of a pattern rule inside the recipe

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, gnu-make, code-cleanup

In a Makefile I have:

```
images/schematic.pdf: images/schematic.svg
      inkscape -D -z --file=$^ --export-pdf=$@ --export-latex
      sed -i "s:schematic:images/schematic:g" $@_tex
```

What this rule does is:

- Use inkscape to convert to a latex-ready `.pdf` PDF file + its corresponding `.pdf_tex` text file (see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2107/104581)
- Modify the mentioned `.pdf_tex` file so that it will not break latex compiling from a "higher" directory (namely `.` when the `.pdf_tex` file is in `./images`)

## My problem:

I have many rules in this form i. e. where only `schematic` is changed. I would like to use a [pattern-rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) that replaces `schematic` by `%`. And to use `%` in the recipe (in the sed command).

However the rule:

```
images/%.pdf: images/%.svg
     inkscape -D -z --file=$^ --export-pdf=$@ --export-latex
     sed -i "s:%:images/%:g" $@_tex
```

does not work: % is interpreted literally in the recipe.

I also tried to replace % in the recipe by $% but this variable seems to be empty.

### Unsatisfactory solution:

Add a line in the recipe to create a (make) variable that will hold the result of `notdir(removeprefix($<))` (using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571391/remove-prefix-with-make) or a call to bash because there is no removeprefix in GNU Make).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want `$*`.
From https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html :

> $*:
> The stem with which an implicit rule matches (see How Patterns Match).
> If the target is dir/a.foo.b and the target pattern is a.%.b
> then the stem is dir/foo. The stem is useful for constructing names of
> related files.
>
> In a static pattern rule, the stem is part of the file name that matched the ‘%’ in the target pattern.
>
> In an explicit rule, there is no stem; so ‘$*’ cannot be determined in that way. Instead, if the target name ends with a
> recognized suffix (see Old-Fashioned Suffix Rules), ‘$*’ is set to the
> target name minus the suffix. For example, if the target name is
> ‘foo.c’, then ‘$*’ is set to ‘foo’, since ‘.c’ is a suffix. GNU make
> does this bizarre thing only for compatibility with other
> implementations of make. You should generally avoid using ‘$*’ except
> in implicit rules or static pattern rules.
>
> If the target name in an explicit rule does not end with a recognized suffix, ‘$*’ is set to the empty string for that rule.

`$%` is an automatic variable, but it's for archive (`.a` library) members, and almost never useful.