# Trying to remove prefix, getting "make: missing separator"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Trying to remove a file prefix using the method proposed in this thread:

[Remove prefix with make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571391/remove-prefix-with-make/19571508)

but even with a copy paste, I'm getting make's missing separator error.

```
FILE=/a/thing    #line 16
$(FILE:a/%=%)    #line 17

Makefile:17: *** missing separator.    Stop.
```

Comment: `/a/thing` --> `a/thing` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When GNU Make processes the following:

```
FILE=a/thing
$(FILE:a/%=%)
```

The `$(FILE:a/%=%)` is *evaluated* to `thing`. That's the problem.

---

What you want is probably:

```
removed-prefix=$(FILE:a/%=%)
```

That is, create a variable `removed-prefix` whose expansion results in `thing`, or:

```
FILE:=$(FILE:a/%=%)
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks a bunch!